# How to loop through XML List

Tags: xml, flex4

```
<fx:XML id="dataGridDataFieldsXML" source="assets/dataGridDataFieldsXML.xml"/>
<s:XMLListCollection id="showGridFields" source="{dataGridDataFieldsXML.viewer}"/>


I want to loop through my XML file and get the "field" value.I tried the following but nothing is getting through the trace statement:

var xmlTrack:XML;

                for each( xmlTrack in dataGridDataFieldsXML.fields_by_viewer.viewer )
                {
                    trace(xmlTrack.@field);
                }


My XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<fields_by_viewer>
    <viewer id="1" field="fieldName1"/>
    <viewer id="1" field="fieldName2"/>
</fields_by_viewer> 

Anything wrong here?

Thanks
flexyboz
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@Craig Mc..this works fine.

I also tried:
fieldsXMLListNew=new XMLListCollection(dataGridDataFieldsXML.viewer as XMLList);

And then looped and got my items using:

for each(var item in fieldsXMLListNew){
item.attribute("field");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
   var myXML:XML = <users>
 <fname>Jane</fname>
 <fname>Susan</fname>
 <fname>John</fname>
</users>;

for each (var item in myXML.fname)
{
    trace(item);
}
/* output
```

More to be found here: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=03_Language_and_Syntax_16.html

Comment: Hello,
I tried the following:

for each( var item in dataGridDataFieldsXML.field){
     Alert.show(item);
    }

still nothing, any idea?

Comment: showGridFields.Node (node being which ever node you want.) And what you want liiks like Attribute not name ;)

xml.attribute("myField")

Comment: So to be clear

its dataGridDataFieldsXML.viewer
trace item.attribute("field")

You see in the way you have done things is you have overloaded viewer which in this case would be the instance, so the for each would be based on viewer not the Attribute field.

Comment: in your existing you could also try:

  {
                    trace(xmlTrack.@field.attribute("field"));
                }

Comment: Thanks Craig Mc..this works fine.

I also tried:
fieldsXMLListNew=new XMLListCollection(dataGridDataFieldsXML.viewer as XMLList);

And then looped and got my items using:

for each(var item in fieldsXMLListNew){
item.attribute("field");
}